# How to refactor a foreach to a single instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, foreach, sql-order-by

I notice that it will only always be one row to catch so i would like to refactor my foreach to something more simple. would should i got about it?

```
WorkShiftTask task = _context.WorkShiftTask.Include(a => a.InHoleSurvey).FirstOrDefault(e => e.WorkShiftTaskId == id); 

foreach (InHoleSurvey member in task.InHoleSurvey.OrderBy(a => a.WorkShiftTask))
{
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(member.InHoleSurveyId);
    TempData["hsId"] = member.InHoleSurveyId;
}
```

This works fine.

```
inHoleSurvey holes = _context.InHoleSurvey.Include(a => a.WorkShiftTask).
                 FirstOrDefault(i => i.WorkShiftTaskId == task.WorkShiftTaskId);
```

This only works when I explicitly give it the URL ID but not when I click on the link.

Comment: Sorry, but nobody knows what you mean by "URL ID" and "click on the link."

Comment: @robbpriestley The question wasnt clear, you are right. but i was simply trying to eliminate my need for the foreach, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying that `task.InHoleSurvey` only ever contains a single element, and you don't need to use the `foreach`, then don't use the `foreach`:

```
WorkShiftTask task = _context.WorkShiftTask.Include(a => a.InHoleSurvey).FirstOrDefault(e => e.WorkShiftTaskId == id); 
InHoleSurvey member = task.InHoleSurvey.FirstOrDefault();
TempData["hsId"] = member.InHoleSurveyId;
```